# How to randomly uppercase characters in a string?

Tags: python, string, random

I want a way of grab an string variable and randomize which letters are uppercase, like so:

```
upperRandomizer("HelloWorld") == "HeLLoWORlD"
```

I've tried this so far:

```
for p in strVar:
        result = ""
        if random.choice((True, False)):
            result += p.upper()
        else:
            result += p
```

But the code only spits out the last letter of the string variable. I tried to use the join() method without success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're redefining `result` as `''` for each iteration. Define it outside the loop

Answer (score 2):

Move your `result` variable outside of the loop. Right now, you are recreating it every time you loop through a character in the list.

```
result = ""
for p in strVar:
    if random.choice((True, False)):
        result += p.upper()
    else:
        result += p
```

Comment: You know what, you are right, i cant believe i havent noticed that up until know. Thanks!

Comment: When the else statement returns result += p.lower(), it will also work when strVar contains uppercases and you want uppercase characters to be randomly converted to lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

**Here you get a oneliner:**

```
import random

def upperRandomizer(string):
    return "".join([char.upper() if random.randint(0,1) == 0 else char for char in string])

print (upperRandomizer("HelloWorld"))
```

Output:

```
HeLLoWorlD
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import random

upperRandomizer = lambda s: ''.join(random.choice((str.upper, str.lower))(x) for x in s)

for _ in range(5):
    print(upperRandomizer('HelloWorld'))
```

Output:

```sh
HELlOwORlD
hELlOWoRLd
HELlowORLd
HELLOwOrLd
HeLLoWorlD
```

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of too much magic, I'd do something like:

```
from random import choice

def caseRandomizer(text):
    return ''.join(map(choice, zip(text.lower(), text.upper())))
```

i.e:

1. get lower and upper case versions of the text
2. use `zip` to iterate over them both character by character
3. `map(choice, ...)` randomly picks either lower or upper character
4. `''.join(...)` turns the iterator back into a string

Warning, I subsequently realised this doesn't work in general.  E.g. `'ß'`, the lowercase German character called eszett, turns into `'SS'` when made uppercase so the upper and lower case versions could go "out of sync".

A version that would work is:

```
from random import choices

def caseRandomizer(text):
    return ''.join(fn(c) for (fn, c) in zip(choices((str.lower, str.upper), k=len(text)), text))
```